# wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module - Python3

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi

I am making use of python3 for building the application

```
[Tue Jan 16 19:07:13.587669 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22631:tid 140432910448384] [remote 172.19.217.162:48145] mod_wsgi (pid=22631): Target WSGI script '/u0/shsathya/html/captool/captool/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jan 16 19:07:13.587752 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22631:tid 140432910448384] [remote 172.19.217.162:48145] mod_wsgi (pid=22631): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/u0/shsathya/html/captool/captool/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 16 19:07:13.587979 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22631:tid 140432910448384] [remote 172.19.217.162:48145] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 16 19:07:13.588026 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22631:tid 140432910448384] [remote 172.19.217.162:48145]   File "/u0/shsathya/html/captool/captool/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Tue Jan 16 19:07:13.588036 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22631:tid 140432910448384] [remote 172.19.217.162:48145]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jan 16 19:07:13.588059 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 22631:tid 140432910448384] [remote 172.19.217.162:48145] ImportError: No module named 'django.core'
```

Comment: You don't have django installed.

Comment: i have installed django using the pip3 utility and i am able to use the django-admin tool and able to run standalone django projects

Comment: What version of Python is your webserver set up to use?  I suspect it's Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: How can u check which version of python my apache2 is using?.  and How to change it to python3?

Comment: To see what Python version you're using, make a simple python web application that just prints the value of `sys.version`.

Comment: so if i create a simple python django project and start the server using the python3 interpreter then it will show me 3.5.x version right?.

Comment: No, you can't make a django project, because your whole problem is that you can't import django in the first place.  Just make a standalone simple script.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @JohnGordon  
root@dev-platops-eng01:/u0/shsathya# python version.py
2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
root@dev-platops-eng01:/u0/shsathya# python3 version.py
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
root@dev-platops-eng01:/u0/shsathya#

Comment: @Alasdair its Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I didn't mean a command-line script, I meant a script that is called by the web server.

Comment: For Ubuntu, make sure that you have installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` and not `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

Comment: libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 i have installed already.  found a problem with that initially.  but  got it resolved with help from stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that django is in PYTHONPATH.
To test import django from a python shell

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>>>import django
>>>
```

---

You need to setup mod_wsgi which has been compiled against python 3 version you use.
Please refer here to verify what version of python your mod_wsgi is compiled for-> http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html

Comment: This is my ldd info for mod_wsgi.py

ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd747c1000)
        libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007ff2a8227000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff2a800a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff2a7c40000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff2a7a17000)